# How does a competing social network get permission to export data through a facebook app?

Tags: facebook-apps

It says in the app agreement that a competing social network has to get permission to export user data to their website.  I noticed that sites like Pinterest and Myspace etc. can do this, did they have to get permission? How does one do this?

-Wayne

Comment: This sounds like a question for a lawyer; that said, we are not lawyers.

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012

> Enter your question into help search and get your answer from our database of common questions. If you can’t troubleshoot your issue with our instructions, we’ll provide you with a custom form to contact us for further support.

I've contacted them for other issues that way and eventually got a reply. It might work for you too. I'm not aware of a direct email address.

There is also a fairly vague section on contacting Facebook here: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/